# Low Level Bidirectional Bind

Tags: javafx, binding, low-level, bidirectional

I have recently discovered bindings and they seem great. I have however stumbled upon a binding I want to make that I cannot seem to figure out. I have a textfield which I want to bind to a double property in a bidirectional way. But, I only want the bind to be from the field to the double property if the text in the field can be converted to a double and if the double it converts to falls within some range. In the other direction I want the bind to be bound without restrictions (I also want to be able to do this for ints but this should be easy once the double one is fixed). I believe this has to be done with a low level bind, doesn't it? How can this be done?

I have just started using bindings and am not great with them so go easy on me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaFX bindings simply add listeners and react accordingly. Thinking like that you could argue that the listeners are the "low-level" aspect of the API. To do what you want you will have to create your own listeners. I am not aware of anything that does what you want "out of the box".

An example that is *not* ready for "production use":

```
public static void bind(TextField field, DoubleProperty property) {
    field.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldText, newText) -> {
        try {
            // If the text can't be converted to a double then an
            // exception is thrown. In this case we do nothing.
            property.set(Double.parseDouble(newText));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {}
    });
    property.addListener((observable, oldNumber, newNumber) -> {
        field.setText(Double.toString(newNumber.doubleValue()));
    });
}
```

This will do what you want if I understood your requirements correctly. I believe this code opens up the possibility of a memory leak, however. Ideally, you'd want the listeners to not keep the other from being garbage collected. For instance, if `property` is no longer strongly referenced then `field` should not keep `property` from being GC'd. *Edit: This code, depending on the implementations of the `ObservableValue`s, could also enter an infinite loop of updates as pointed out in the comments*.

---

**Edit: The first "robust" example I gave had some issues and didn't provide a way to *unbind* the properties from each other. I've changed the example to make it more correct and also provide said *unbinding* feature. This new example is based on how the developers of JavaFX handled bidirectional binding internally.**

A more robust code example of what I gave above. This is heavily "inspired" by the code used by the standard JavaFX internal APIs. Specifically the class `com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding`.

```
import javafx.beans.WeakListener;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Objects;

public class CustomBindings {

    // This code is based heavily on how the standard JavaFX API handles bidirectional bindings. Specifically,
    // the class 'com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding'.

    public static void bindBidirectional(StringProperty stringProperty, DoubleProperty doubleProperty) {
        if (stringProperty == null || doubleProperty == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        BidirectionalBinding binding = new BidirectionalBinding(stringProperty, doubleProperty);
        stringProperty.addListener(binding);
        doubleProperty.addListener(binding);
    }

    public static void unbindBidirectional(StringProperty stringProperty, DoubleProperty doubleProperty) {
        if (stringProperty == null || doubleProperty == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        // The equals(Object) method of BidirectionalBinding was overridden to take into
        // account only the properties. This means that the listener will be removed even
        // though it isn't the *same* (==) instance.
        BidirectionalBinding binding = new BidirectionalBinding(stringProperty, doubleProperty);
        stringProperty.removeListener(binding);
        doubleProperty.removeListener(binding);
    }

    private static class BidirectionalBinding implements ChangeListener<Object>, WeakListener {

        private final WeakReference<StringProperty> stringRef;
        private final WeakReference<DoubleProperty> doubleRef;

        // Need to cache it since we can't hold a strong reference
        // to the properties. Also, a changing hash code is never a
        // good idea and it needs to be "insulated" from the fact
        // the properties can be GC'd.
        private final int cachedHashCode;

        private boolean updating;

        private BidirectionalBinding(StringProperty stringProperty, DoubleProperty doubleProperty) {
            stringRef = new WeakReference<>(stringProperty);
            doubleRef = new WeakReference<>(doubleProperty);

            cachedHashCode = Objects.hash(stringProperty, doubleProperty);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean wasGarbageCollected() {
            return stringRef.get() == null || doubleRef.get() == null;
        }

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            if (!updating) {
                StringProperty stringProperty = stringRef.get();
                DoubleProperty doubleProperty = doubleRef.get();
                if (stringProperty == null || doubleProperty == null) {
                    if (stringProperty != null) {
                        stringProperty.removeListener(this);
                    }
                    if (doubleProperty != null) {
                        doubleProperty.removeListener(this);
                    }
                } else {
                    updating = true;
                    try {
                        if (observable == stringProperty) {
                            updateDoubleProperty(doubleProperty, (String) newValue);
                        } else if (observable == doubleProperty) {
                            updateStringProperty(stringProperty, (Number) newValue);
                        } else {
                            throw new AssertionError("How did we get here?");
                        }
                    } finally {
                        updating = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void updateStringProperty(StringProperty property, Number newValue) {
            if (newValue != null) {
                property.set(Double.toString(newValue.doubleValue()));
            } else {
                // set the property to a default value such as 0.0?
                property.set("0.0");
            }
        }

        private void updateDoubleProperty(DoubleProperty property, String newValue) {
            if (newValue != null) {
                try {
                    property.set(Double.parseDouble(newValue));
                } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
                    // newValue is not a valid double
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return cachedHashCode;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }

            StringProperty stringProperty1 = stringRef.get();
            DoubleProperty doubleProperty1 = doubleRef.get();

            if (stringProperty1 == null || doubleProperty1 == null) {
                return false;
            }

            if (obj instanceof BidirectionalBinding) {
                BidirectionalBinding other = (BidirectionalBinding) obj;
                StringProperty stringProperty2 = other.stringRef.get();
                DoubleProperty doubleProperty2 = other.doubleRef.get();
                if (stringProperty2 == null || doubleProperty2 == null) {
                    return false;
                }

                return stringProperty1 == stringProperty2 && doubleProperty1 == doubleProperty2;
            }

            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Ah okay. This is essentially what I am doing already. Doesn't this example introduce an infinite loop of binds though (I don't have my computer to check it now unfortunately)?

Comment: @IvarEriksson The way properties are implemented in the standard API is in such a way so they only fire events if the value has _truly_ changed. So, I _think_ in this case there won't be any infinite loops. But you're right that this code is brittle. I'll try to fix it up.

Comment: Okay great. I wish I knew more stuff like this but I suppose that comes with experience. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No worries I'm just grateful for the help.